# Cannot inject default MySQL datasource

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, datasource, quarkus

I am trying hard to inject the default datasource but I have the following error:

> javax.enterprise.inject.IllegalProductException: Normal scoped producer method may not return null:
>   io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSourceProducer.createDefaultDataSource()

This is my current situation:

application.properties

```
quarkus.datasource.driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/sandbox
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.password=password
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=0
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=11
```

MyClass.java

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    AgroalDataSource dataSource;

    void methodUsingDataSource() {...}
}
```

However I made it works with a named datasource with the **SAME** configuration as the default one:

application.properties

```
quarkus.datasource.users.driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
quarkus.datasource.users.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/sandbox
quarkus.datasource.users.username=root
quarkus.datasource.users.password=password
quarkus.datasource.users.min-size=0
quarkus.datasource.users.max-size=11
```

MyClass.java

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    @DataSource("users")
    AgroalDataSource dataSource;

    void methodUsingDataSource() {...}
}
```

Do you have any idea about how to fix this behaviour? This causes me issues when I want to setup Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
quarkus.datasource.driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

and use this instead:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind = mysql
```

You're mixing deprecated and new configuration properties in the default datasource and your combination of it doesn't work.

The example you gave with the named datasource is only using the old configuration properties so it works OK.

Now I need to understand why you didn't have a proper error message. I'll go work on improving that.

Comment: The application does not start with this configuration.

I get the following error : Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource and qualifiers [@Default]

Comment: Which version of Quarkus is this?

Comment: This is 1.2.0.Final

Comment: Everything is fine now since I updated the quarkus version from 1.2.0.Final to 1.4.1.Final. Thank you for your support!

Comment: Yeah, so the story is that we changed the datasource config and you were using some properties that weren't supported by 1.2 in the configuration of your default datasource. That's why it didn't get created.